# monkey patch add new class and functions to existing module

Tags: python, monkeypatching

If I have an existing module `track.py` that looks like:

```
class A:
   variable_b = "some text"
```

How can I patch `track.py` to add a new class and a new function like:

```
class A:
   variable_b = "some text"

class B:
   variable_c = "more text"

def some_func():
   pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're saying that track.py is inaccessible (perhaps from a library you don't want to touch).

There's a couple ways you could do it. One is to just import the module then at runtime alter the object to include the class.

```
import track
track.B = B  # or setattr(track, 'B', B)
track.some_func = some_func  # or settattr(track, 'some_func', some_func)
```

You could also merge in the __init__.py e.g.

```
import track
import track_monkey_patch
track.__dict__.update(track_monkey_patch.__dict__)
```

Also, along the lines of making a decorator or some kind of wrapping to just do it for you, if you are okay adding an external dependency then it looks like someone has done this (never used it myself, just a quick google).
https://github.com/christophercrouzet/gorilla

Test code that anyone could use

```
import collections  # could have been anything just came to my head quickly
def foo():
    print("foooooo")
collections.foo = foo
collections.foo()
>>> foooooo
```

Comment: When trying to patch in 'B' its just says: module 'track' has no attribute 'B'

Comment: @user3831011 That's strange. What version of Python are you using? I suppose you could try setattr but it's the same thing.

Comment: Im on 3.8, and setattr does the same thing

Comment: How does your folder structure look like? Or is this a module installed via pip?

Comment: its a pip installed library, i had already monkey patched a few classes/functions, but the way to library works I have to add a new class and hook it into a few things as well.

Comment: Ah, I think the problem might be another module inside that library is attempting to call it before it gets patched in. Think this is a self caused type of issue